# Duals of a finite dimensional eveloping coalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, coalgebras

Let $C^e$ be the enveloping $k$-coalgebra of a $k$-coalgebra $C$ and denote by ${C^e}^{\star}:=\mathrm{Hom}\,_{k}(C^e,k)$.

Then is ${C^e}^{\star} \cong {C^{\star}}^e$?

Comment: Can you say what $C$ is and what the enveloping $k$-coalgebra is?  Something is definitely wrong here as, whatever your definitions are, $(C^e)^*$ is an algebra (being the dual of a coalgebra), while $(C^*)^e$ is a coalgebra (being the enveloping coalgebra of something).

Comment: Well what if I assumed C where to be a bialgebra of finite dimension... (here k is a field)

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces, there is a canonical isomorphism $(V\otimes W)^*\cong V^*\otimes W^*$. Can you prove this? Notice this is plain linear algebra. Once you've done that, you should be able to answer your question.

Comment: Hmm.. ok true it is trivial in that case, then If I no longer assumed C to be finite dimensional...

Comment: I am not sure if the category-theory tag is really appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note, all homs and tensors will be over $k$)

Let $C$ be a coalgebra.  The enveloping coalgebra of $C$ is $C^e:=C\otimes C^{op}$.  Similarly, we can define the enveloping algebra of an algebra by $A^e:=A\otimes A^{op}$.  We have that op commutes with dualization, in the sense that if $C$ is a coalgebra, then $(C^*)^{op}\cong (C^{op})^*$ as algebras.

Given vector spaces $V, W$, we have a natural map $V^*\otimes W^* \to (V\otimes W)^*$ given sending $\phi \otimes \psi$ to the map $v\otimes w \mapsto (\phi(v)\otimes \psi(w))$.  If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, this map is an isomorphism.  One proof is to take a basis for $V,W$, and then examine the corresponding dual bases.

However, if $V$ and $W$ are both infinite, the map is no longer an isomorphism.  We can factor the natural map as 
$$\hom(V,k)\otimes \hom(W,k)\to \hom(V,\hom(W,k))\cong \hom(V\otimes W,k).$$  Since the last maps is an isomorphism, the natural map is an isomorphism if and only if the first map is.  We assert that it is not.

Let $Z=\hom(W,k).$  An element of $\hom(V,k)\otimes Z$ is a finite sums of the form $\sum \phi_i \otimes z_i$, which under our map is sent to $v\to \sum \phi(i)v z_i$.  The image of such a map is finite dimensional.  Since $V$ and $Z$ are both infinite dimensional, there are maps in $\hom(V,Z)$ with infinite image, and therefore our map cannot be surjective.

---

It is worth pointing out that the failure of tensor products to commute with dualization means that while the dual of a coalgebra is an algebra, the dual of an infinite dimensional algebra is NOT in general a coalgebra.

Suppose we have a map $\Delta:C\to C\otimes C$.  Dualizaing and precomposing with the natural map, we have $C^* \otimes C^* \to (C\otimes C)^* \stackrel{\Delta^*}{\to} C^*$.

However if we have a map $\mu:A\otimes A\to A$, we cannot in general factor $\mu^*:A^*\to (A\otimes A)^*$ through $A^*\otimes A^*$.

One solution to this is to view dualization not as a controvatiant functor from vector spaces to itself, but rather a pair of controvariant functors between vector spaces and topological vector space with the pro-finite topology.

Comment: Wow!  that was a perfect answer!
Thank you very very much Aaron :D

Comment: You're welcome.  And for more information about my final paragraph, one quick reference is page 22 (section 2.5) of [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5859.pdf).  Then coalgebras in vector spaces are dual to algebras in profinite vector spaces.